# Angular datatable select rows with data

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I need to render a new table based on selected rows.
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/rowSelect

I need to pass the entire object instead of

```
ng-model="selected[' + full.id + ']"
```

which only prints in the format

```
{id:boolean}
```

Say for ex: `full` is a `User object-> user.id, user.name, user.email`. I would like to have `isSelected: boolean` as additional property injected to user object. So I could easily construct a new table from the user object when `isSelected` is true.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have to use ng-datatables or could you use UI-Grid? I'm asking because I can do this in UI-Grid, but I haven't looked at datatables at all.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I have to do this in Angular datatable...

Comment: @PondicherryFellow Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am trying to simply return just the `{id}` of all 'selected' items rather than `{id:boolean}` of every item regardless.